# Launching with parameters (was "How to block until a master is running")

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosparam, rosmaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a script that wraps `rosbag play` (because I need to set some rosparams first). However, if I run my script before my master finishes coming up, my calls to `rosparam set` fail, and my parameters don't get set (the call to `play` blocks until the master is up).

Is there a convenient way to block until a master comes up? I could write a miniature node that does it, but I thought I'd ask.

Another possibility: arguably, this is a bug in `rosparam`; it should either (a) block until it has a master or (b) at least provide a non-zero return code when it dies with "Unable to communicate with master", so I can spinblock it myself.

Thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10879/launching-with-parameters-(was-%22how-to-block-until-a-master-is-running%22)/) by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4119 on 2011-08-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure that I fully understand your use case, but you might try [roslaunch args](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/arg).  Here's a launch file that sets two params from arguments:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="my_integer_param" default="1"/>
  <arg name="my_string_param" default="foobar"/>
  <param name="my_integer_param" value="$(arg my_integer_param)"/>
  <param name="my_string_param" value="$(arg my_string_param)"/>
  <node name="rosplay" pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" args="play /tmp/mybag.bag"/>
</launch>
```

Defaults for the args are given, so you can launch it normally:

```
roslaunch foo.launch
```

But you can override them on the [command-line](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools#Passing_in_args), e.g.:

```
roslaunch foo.launch my_integer_param:=42 my_string_param:=barfoo
```

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using this to wait for a rosmaster:

```
until rostopic list ; do sleep 1; done
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just wondering. Would it be more convenient to put all of these in a launch file?

---

Originally posted by [Zack](https://answers.ros.org/users/949/zack/) with karma: 216 on 2011-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-12**:
You can use arguments from the command line.  http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/arg

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-08-12**:
In this case, it wouldn't, unless there's some way to read command-line arguments in roslaunch.